# get the row data by a button in a react-bootstrap-table

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I'm using react-bootstrap-table (var ReactBsTable = require("react-bootstrap-table")).
I tried to add a button which on click display the id or the row data correspondent to this button row.
 I used jquery but I give an id to the button but all these buttons would have the same id (validatebutton) so just the first one work and the rest no because I can't have the same id for many components.

Any idea please.

```
<BootstrapTable data={this.state.activities} pagination={true} hover={true} search={true} selectRow={selectRowProp} options={options}>
<TableHeaderColumn isKey={true} dataField="id" hidden {true}>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
<TableHeaderColumn dataField="title" dataSort={true}>Title</TableHeaderColumn>
<TableHeaderColumn dataField="adress" dataSort{true}>Adress</TableHeaderColumn>
<TableHeaderColumn dataField="button" dataFormat={this.buttonFunction}></TableHeaderColumn>

</BootstrapTable>

buttonFunction: function (cell, row) {
    var today = new Date().toISOString();
    if (row.status === "En cours") {
        if (row.dateEnd > today) {
            return <Alert_Validate></Alert_Validate>;
        } else {
            return <label>
                <button type="button" id="validatebutton" onClick=     {this._validateFunction} className="bbtn btn-primary btn-sm"><i className="fa fa-check fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            </label>

        }
    }
},

 _validateFunction: function () {
    var userid=this.props.params.id;
    $("#validatebutton").click(function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
         var activityid = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)");
        console.log("activity id :"+activityid.text());
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of searching for your data through the DOM, you could pass it as a parameter to your _validateFunction:

```
buttonFunction(cell, row) {      
  return <label>
            <button type="button" 
                    id="validatebutton" 
                    onClick={() => {this._validateFunction(row)}} 
                    className="bbtn btn-primary btn-sm">
                      Click Me
            </button>
         </label>        
}
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate it: https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/5asms7j7/

Comment: really I appreciate your help #omerts#. It works at me.Can you explain for me why it works when I use  ( onClick={() => {this._validateFunction(row)}}) and no if I use ( onClick={{this._validateFunction(row)}). Tnk you

Comment: Using the latter calls the function right away, without waiting for the click, and the result of the function is stored for the onClick handler. The first method basically creates an anonymous function which wraps the call to the _validateFunction, and only when the user clicks it raises the _validateFunction. In es5, it would be onClick={(function(){this._validateFunction}).bind(this)}. (Using () => auto binds the this var).

Comment: Tnk you for your answer.

Comment: @omerts I have a similar issue, I would like to display the button conditionally. I'm trying to compare the `ids` of the objects in my database and compare them to the `row.id`. depending on the result I would like to display a different button. Can you please have a look at my SO question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244914/how-to-conditionally-render-the-button-in-react-bootstrap-table-the-button-fo

Comment: @AziCode, sorry for the late response, I saw you already got an answer :)