# How to conditionally render the button in react-bootstrap-table ? (The button for each row)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-bootstrap-table

I'm trying to conditionally render the button in the `react-bootstrap-table` by comparing the row.id  with the item.id from my database.

I managed to add a button by using a the `dataFormat` prop, but I'm having trouble to display a button conditionally

- I'm using the table to display groups that I get from my database.
- once I fetch all the groups, I compare their ids (row.id) with the groups that I have on my database.
- If they match I display `Button1`
- If they don't match I display `Button2`

I tried many attempts but my solutions are not giving me the desired result

Here's my code :

- If I already have 8 groups in the database, the buttons of the 8 groups should be `red` with a different text than the other buttons.
- and if the group is not in the database, it's button should be `blue`

  ```
  class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
       json: [], // json(coming from the Meetup-api)
       jsonFromDatabase: [],
    }
    this.cellButton = this.cellButton.bind(this);
   }

  cellButton(cell, row, enumObject, rowIndex) {
    let theButton
    for(var group in this.state.jsonFromDatabase){
    if (this.state.jsonFromDatabase[group].id !== row.id){
       // Display this button if the group is not in the database
       theButton = <button style={{ backgroundColor: "blue"}}
                       type="button"
                       onClick={() => this.onClickGroupSelected(cell, row, rowIndex)}>
                     Process the group
                   </button>
     } else {
       // Display this button if the group is already in the database
       theButton = <button style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
                       type="button"
                       onClick={() => this.onClickGroupToUpdate(cell, row, rowIndex)}>
                     Update the group
                   </button>
       }
     }
    return theButton
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <BootstrapTable data={this.state.json} options={ this.options } >
             <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id' width='100'>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name' width='300'>Group Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='button' width='100' dataFormat={this.cellButton}>Generate Group Page</TableHeaderColumn>
          </BootstrapTable>
      )
    }
  }
  ```

Another unsuccessful variation that I tried:

```
  cellButton(cell, row, enumObject, rowIndex) {
  let theButton

  Object.keys(this.state.jsonFromDatabase).map((key) => {
  if (this.state.jsonFromDatabase[key].id  !== row.id){
    return (
      <button style={{ backgroundColor: "blue"}}
          type="button"
          onClick={() => this.onClickGroupSelected(cell, row, rowIndex)}>
         Process the group
      </button>
    )
   } else {
       ....
       ....
   }
  })
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems correct but implementation is a bit wrong.

```
cellButton(cell, row, enumObject, rowIndex) {
  let theButton;
  let groupExistsInDatabase = false;
  for(var group in this.state.jsonFromDatabase){
    if (this.state.jsonFromDatabase[group].id === row.id){
      // make groupExistsInDatabase true if the group is found in the database
      groupExistsInDatabase = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if(groupExistsInDatabase === true) {
    theButton = <button style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} type="button" onClick={() => this.onClickGroupToUpdate(cell, row, rowIndex)}>
                  Update the group
                </button>
  } else {
    theButton = <button style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }} type="button" onClick={() => this.onClickGroupSelected(cell, row, rowIndex)}>
                  Process the group
                </button>
  }
  return theButton;
}
```

This solution should work. Let me know if there are some modifications.

Comment: Great this solution works fine, but could you please change the `!==` into an `===` . Because the goal there is to check if `group.id` that is stored in the database is equal to the `row.id`. Apart from that it's working fine

Comment: Quick question, let's say I want to temporarily change the Button text when the user clicks. ex: If the user taps on the `Process the group` button, the text would change to `Processing` for 1 sec just to give some time for fetching the data. How would you approach that ? I tried doing that using `setState` when the button is pressed but It's changing all the buttons ?

Comment: @AziCode I think for this you can use setState but store the `cell row and column as well` and for that row and column change the text. And when your data is fetched then remove that cell row and column from setState. Both these operations can be done in `componentWillUpdate()`

Comment: I actually found a solution: I basically store the `rowIndex` in the `state` when the user taps on the `button`. Then in the cellButton function I check if the stored `rowIndex` is `===` to the `rowIndex` and display the appropriate text  on the `Button`, this way I can show the user that an action is being executed. thanks

Comment: @AziCode cheers for that. But try to click multiple buttons at the same time, text must be there for all of them and clicking on one button should not change `loading` state of another

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you are `returning` one one button from cell formatter `function`.

Use this:

```
cellButton(cell, row, enumObject, rowIndex) {
    let uiItems = [];
    for(var group in this.state.jsonFromDatabase){
        if (this.state.jsonFromDatabase[group].id !== row.id){
            uiItems.push(<button style={{ backgroundColor: "blue"}}
                            type="button"
                            onClick={() => this.onClickGroupSelected(cell, row, rowIndex)}>
                                Process the group
                        </button>)
        }else{
                uiItems.push(<button style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
                                type="button"
                                onClick={() => this.onClickGroupToUpdate(cell, row, rowIndex)}>
                                   Update the group
                            </button>)
        }
    }
    return uiItems;
}
```

or use `map`, like this:

```
cellButton(cell, row, enumObject, rowIndex) {
    return this.state.jsonFromDatabase.map((group, i) => {
        if (group.id !== row.id){
            return  <button style={{ backgroundColor: "blue"}}
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => this.onClickGroupSelected(cell, row, rowIndex)}>
                            Process the group
                    </button>
        }else{
            return  <button style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
                        type="button"
                         onClick={() => this.onClickGroupToUpdate(cell, row, rowIndex)}>
                            Update the group
                    </button>
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it in my question, but I actually do `bind` the format function in the constructor ( I edited my question )

Comment: buttons are not reflecting in ui? one more thing put the console.log in this function and check is it going inside this or not.

Comment: It is going inside the function, as you can see in the screenshot. I return  a red Btn if the group is already in the database, and a blue Btn when it's not.

Comment: then what's the issue ?

Comment: Well in my `this.state.jsonFromDatabase` I have 8 groups that have similar `ids` than groups that are in `this.state.json`. So the goal is to iterate through the objects and when I find similar groups I display a `red Btn`, otherwise I display a `blue Btn`. The issue is that the function is displaying only 1 `red Btn` while it should display 8 of them.

Comment: What would I do with uiItems?  are you familiar with `react-bootstrap-table`, that's what I'm using

Comment: just return that uiItems from cell formatter function, it will be an array that will contain all the buttons, like i did. yes i am very familiar with `react-bootstrap-table` :)

Comment: Oh I see, you might be right actually. So basically your solution should modify all the uiItems then return the modified items. That will be passed to the `react-bootstrap-table`. I'll try it out and I'll let you know

Comment: Both answers don't work:
the `map` version spits back `Uncaught TypeError: this.state. jsonFromDatabase.map is not a function`.

and the 1st answer is not returning the buttons but instead of the buttons I'm getting `[object Object],[object Object]` displayed on screen

Comment: map should work, write this `dataFormat={this.cellButton.bind(this)}`, in place of `dataFormat={this.cellButton}`.

Comment: It still giving me the same error `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.jsonFromDatabase.map is not a function` .
On the line `return this.state.jsonFromFirebase.map((group, i) => {`

Comment: make sure `jsonFromDatabase` should be an array, otherwise it will throw this error.

Comment: `jsonFromDatabase` is an `array of objects of objects` ex: `jsonFromDatabase = [ object1: { key1: value1, key2 : value2, key3 : value3 } , object2: { key1: value1, key2: value2, key3 : value3 } ] `